# Unable to view console/logging output when using Avalonia

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I'm trying to print to stdout with Avalonia from inside my `MainWindow.axaml.cs` file. I'm unable to view the output of `Console.WriteLine`. [This github ticket](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/3629) says to use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`, but that doesn't work either. It does however point to [this wiki page](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/getting-started/logging-errors-and-warnings) about Avalonia's logging infrastructure, but that page doesn't have examples of using the logging. After some digging, I saw the following usages throughout a lot of Avalonia code

```csharp
using Avalonia.Logging;
// ...
Logger.TryGet(/* event level */, /* log area */)?.Log(/* calling object */, "log string")
// example
Logger.TryGet(LogEventLevel.Warning, LogArea.Visual)?.Log(this, "TryGetPointAndTangentAtDistance is not available in Direct2D.");
```

I've tried specifying different `LoggingLevels` and `LoggingAreas` within the main method, as well as placing the logging before and after `InitializeComponent` in the constructor, but nothing seems to work.

Steps to reproduce:

1. create new dotnet app with Avalonia.MVMM template
2. Place any of the mentioned logging attempts (writeline, system diagnostics, avalonia.logging) inside of `Views/MainWindow.axaml.cs`
3. `dotnet run` will open up the welcome to Avalonia window, but the console won't have any output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attaching a debugger (VS Debugging or Rider) and viewing the Debug output will show anything logged via `Logger.TryGet` and `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`. Creating a new project and with the following `MainWindow.axaml.cs`:

```
using Avalonia.Logging;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Logger.TryGet(LogEventLevel.Fatal, LogArea.Control)?.Log(this, "Avalonia Infrastructure");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("System Diagnostics Debug");
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Shows the following output in the Rider debug output:

```
...
[Control] Avalonia Infrastructure (MainWindow #33726620)
System Diagnostics Debug
...
```

[image: Screenshot of output from Rider Debug console]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a visual studio project, you can edit the project file to enable the console window. NOTE: Your MainWindow will still be shown as well. The console window will display all Console.Write data as expected.

Right click on the project in Solution Explorer and select Edit Project File.
Under PropertyGroup change OutputType from WinExe to just Exe and add the following element to make it work on non Framework versions of .NET.

```
<DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>
```

This is what it should look like.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    ...
    <DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>
  </PropertyGroup>
```